# Multiple UIActionSheets in one View Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

How are multiple `UIActionSheet`s added to a single `UIViewController` if there is only a single `-actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a Name or Tag to your Action sheet and do some thing like this

```
  -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
   if(actionSheet==yourActionsheet1)
     {
      //your logic
       }
     if(actionSheet==yourActionsheet2)
     {
      //your logic
       }
    }
```

hope this help

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to set the button colors? e.g. a red Delete button?

Comment: @Helium3: Red color is by default color for destructive button titles in actionsheet. You just have to declare `destructiveButtonTitle=@"Delete"` while declaring actionsheet. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

You can create multiple action sheet as below:

```
actionSheet1 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Where to go"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:@"Store 2"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Store 3",@"Store 4",@"Store 5",@"View Store Profile",nil];
 actionSheet2 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Where to go"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:@"Store 1"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Store 3",@"Store 4",@"Store 5",@"View Store Profile",nil];
actionSheet3 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Where to go"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:@"Store 1"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Store 2",@"Store 4",@"Store 5",@"View Store Profile",nil];
```

& after that chek out which action sheet is called by
- (void) actionSheet: (UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

```
if(actionSheet==actionSheet1)
{
}
else if(actionSheet==actionSheet2)
{
}
else if(actionSheet==actionSheet3)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple action sheets to the same view controller. You can set a tag for each of the action sheets and check the tag in the delegate method to perform the necessary function.